# Issues running Supervisord via Homebrew

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery, homebrew, supervisord

I'm a little confused about the process for starting/running Supervisor. I've installed it via `brew install supervisor`. I have all of my .conf files (celery, rabbitmq, redis) built and in the correct directory.

So I start supervisor: `brew services start supervisor`. After it successfully starts I run `supervisorctl start all`, to which I get the following reply:

```
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
```

I was able to get supervisor running in the past without uncommenting or any configurations in the supervisord.conf file, so I don't know what to make of this issue now.

I've tried other inputs found online. Here are the outputs:

**Input:** `supervisorctl restart all`
**Output:** `http://localhost:9001 refused connection`

**Input:** `supervisord -c /usr/local/etc/supervisord.conf`
**Output:** `Error: File contains no section headers. file: '/usr/local/etc/redis.conf', line: 80 'bind 127.0.0.1 -::1\n'`

**Input:** `ps aux | grep supervisord`
**Output:** `user  90580   0.0  0.0 407963472    400 s002  U+   10:04AM   0:00.00 grep supervisord`

Any advice on solving the localhost issue? Also, why am I getting different response when I use `supervisord -c /usr/local/etc/supervisord.conf`and `supervisorctl start all`? Don't these two commands execute the same function? Lastly, why am I suddenly being asked for section headers from the redis.conf file. Like I said...confused. This is my first time doing any of this, so feel free to assume I know nothing.